# Is it possible to count the number of squats with Computer Vision techniques?

Tags: computer-vision

I am planning to build an app which will count the number of sqauts from videos. Assuming that the user and camera do not move, are there ways I can count the number of squats? Do such models to understand human activity and pose exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily using Posenet or Openpose. Train the keypoints for Squats and then count it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a rather straightforward problem that should be able to be solved using openCV or ANNs.

Check out this paper to get you started: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08936.pdf